# I want to get application crash info in Android programmatically without using 3rd party apps or jars like bugsense etc

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, crash-dumps

I have a webview based android application I want to get the crash report and store it into a text file but i am unable to find any programmatic native solution anywhere. I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo.html) article but I am unable to use it. I have no code because I dont know where to start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517762/how-to-send-crash-reports-data-to-your-own-service-written-in-net

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle crash logs is creating an UncaughtExceptionHandler and handling it as per your requirement. Create a BaseActivity class and extend all the Activities with that and put this code stuff in the BaseActivity class.

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handleAppCrash = 
                                     new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        Log.e("error", ex.toString());
        //send email here
    }
};
```

Then just enable is inside onCreate() method of your BaseActivity by using

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handleAppCrash);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am catching un-handled exceptions by using this in my activity's onCreate():

```
mUEHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            try {

                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        openFileOutput(DMP_FILENAME, 0)));
                e.printStackTrace(pw);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // do nothing
            }
            BaseActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUEHandler);
```

This writes every unhandled exception in your app that happened on your activity to text file. Then you can analyze it.

Comment: He is asking for "ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo" crash reporting in question, not Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. Please check the link.

Comment: @Syed : Did above code shared by me help you what you want ?

Comment: @Rollno1 No this i already have implemented what i want is a way to know on each restart of application that whether it was crashed last time or not. The crash can also be operating system closing our app if memory was low and this event is not caught in the above code

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you log every thing like Log.e("tag","msg") or else check the logcat for the crashes

Comment: thats the point i basically wanna get the logcat every time the application runs and check if it was crashed last time. So how to check that with logs?

Comment: You can always check the crashes in the logcat

Comment: But how to check by reading a text file that application was last crashed when it closed on opening of it?

Comment: @SyedWajahatAli Did you got the solution you were looking for? as I am also searching for the same, any help would be appreciated..