# how to send crash reports data to your own service written in .net

Tags: android

I have implemented code of cloudant but i want report to be send to my service hosted somewhere

```
@ReportsCrashes(

        formUri = "https://medo.cloudant.com/acra-example/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
        reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
        formUriBasicAuthLogin = "tubtakedstinumenterences",
        formUriBasicAuthPassword = "igqMFFMatvtMXVCKgy7u6a5W",
        formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
        customReportContent = {
             ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
                ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
                ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
                ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
                ReportField.REPORT_ID,
                ReportField.BUILD,
                ReportField.STACK_TRACE,    
        },

        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.toast_crash

)
```

**MainApp**

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA

        ACRA.init(this);

       // ReportField[] arrayreports=mReportsCrashes.customReportContent();     

    }

}
```